# Should I use <![CDATA[...]]> in HTML5?

Tags: cdata, html

I'm pretty sure `<![CDATA[...]]>` sections can be used in XHTML5, but what about HTML5?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The `CDATA` structure isn't really for HTML at all, it's for XML.

People sometimes use them in XHTML inside `script` tags because it removes the need for them to escape `<`, `>` and `&` characters. It's unnecessary in HTML though, since `script` tags in HTML are already parsed like CDATA sections.

**Edit:** This is where we open that really mouldy old can of worms from 2002 over whether you're sending XHTML as `text/html` or as `application/xhtml+xml` like you’re “supposed” to :-)

Comment: I am sending HTML (not XHTML) and I want that. Thxs for the answer :)

Comment: Can use `CDATA` inside a `pre` tag so I don't have to fix all my angle brackets?

Comment: Inexact. CDATA is for both SGML and the XML subset. So it's for both HTML and XHTML.

Comment: @gman No, `pre` elements are not special.

Comment: @JohanBoulé That depends on what you mean. To clarify, SGML can mark elements to have CDATA content, while XML can use `<![CDATA[` .. `]]>` in the source.

Comment: @MrLister Exactly. I'm OK with the answer, but the first sentence doesn't look right. "The CDATA structure isn't really for HTML." CDATA came with SGML, and HTML is SGML, so the sentence doesn't process in a logical way.

Answer (score 26):

From the same page [@pst linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3302668/):

> [Element-specific parsing for `script` and `style` tags](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/HTML_vs._XHTML#Element-specific_parsing), *Guidance for XHTML-HTML compatibility*: "The following code with escaping can ensure script and style elements will work in both XHTML and HTML, including older browsers."

Maximum backwards compatibility:

```html
<script type="text/javascript"><!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
    ...
//--><!]]></script>
```

Simpler version, sort of incompatible with "much older browsers":

```html
<script>//<![CDATA[
   ...
//]]></script>
```

So, `CDATA` can be used in HTML5, and it's recommended in the official *Guidance for XHTML-HTML compatibility*.

This useful for [*polyglot* HTML/XML/XHTML pages](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/HTML_vs._XHTML#Overlap_Language), which are served as strict `application/xml` XML during development, but served as `text/html` HTML5 in production mode for better cross-browser compatibility. [Polyglot pages have their benefits](http://www.xmlplease.com/xhtml/xhtml5polyglot/); I've used this myself, as it's much easier to debug XML/XHTML5. Google Chrome, for example, will throw an error for invalid XML/XHTML5 (including for example [character escaping](https://technikh.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/chrome-xml-error/)), whereas the same page served as HTML5 will "just work" also known as "probably work".

Comment: the comments within a script tag are needed if you want to support  some 20 year old browsers, that is NSCA Mosaic or Netscape 1...

Answer (score 18):

The spec seems to clear up this issue.  script and style tags are considered to be "raw text elements."  CDATA is not needed or allowed for them.  CDATA is only used with "foreign content" - i.e. MathML and SVG.  Note that there are some restrictions to what can go in the script tag -- basically you can't put something like `var x = '</script>'` in there because it will close the tag and needs to be split like pst noted in his answer. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#cdata-rcdata-restrictions

Answer (score 12):

**HTML5-supporting browsers (and most older browsers going all the way back to 2001) already read the content inside `<style>` and `<script>` tags as CDATA (character data).** That means you generally do ***not*** need to add CDATA tags inside those elements for most HTML browsers built the past 20 years as they will parse any special characters ok that might popup when adding CSS and JavaScript code between them.

However...you do need to add the CDATA block inside `<style>` and `<script>` HTML5 tags **if you want your HTML5 page to be compatible with XHTML and XML browsers and parsers**, which do need CDATA tags. For that reason, **I do recommend you use CDATA in HTML5** `<style>` and `<script>` tags, but please read on. If you do not do this right, *you will break your website*!

Note: The *CDATA tag* helps XML parsers ignore special characters that might popup in between those elements, which are part of XML elements, and therefore which would break the markup (like using `<` or `>` characters, for example). Only the `<style>` and `<script>` in modern HTML parses have this special feature already built in. That simply means in HTML browsers and parsers they are designed to ignore those weird characters, or rather not read or parse them, as part of the markup. If they did not have built in CDATA properties, your web page, styles, and scripts could break!

XML and XHTML parsers will read the `<style>` and `<script>` tag content as they do all HTML elements, as PCDATA (i.e. a normal HTML element), meaning the contents are parsed as markup and potentially break with special characters added in between those tags. You can add special CDATA sections between those two tags to support it. Because XML and XHTML parsers reads everything inside elements as potentially more markup, adding CDATA prevents certain characters from being interpreted as XML or other types of character references.

The problem is, most HTML4/HTML5 browsers and parsers don't support adding additional CDATA sections between those tags, so CDATA blocks have to be commented out for those agents if you add them for XHTML/XML support.

Also, note that all HTML comments (`<!--` or `-->`) added inside those tags are ignored by HTML parsers, but implemented by XHTML ones, commenting out CSS and JavaScript for XHTML, when added. Many people in the past would add comment rules between those tags to hide styles and scripts from very old browsers that normally would not understand CSS or Javascript (pre-1998 browsers). But that strategy failed in XHTML without additional code.

So how do you combine all that inside `<style>` and `<script>` tags, and should you care?

I am a purist and like my **HTML5** content to still be **XML/XHTML-friendly**, regardless of what markup recommendation I am using. I also like my pages to work in browsers that know CSS and older browsers that do not. So here are two solutions to support all those scenarios and still display your styles and scripts in modern browsers without error. **They are totally safe to use in modern HTML5 browsers**:

STYLE

```
<style type="text/css">
    <!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/

    ...put your styles here

    /*]]>*/-->
</style>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--

    ...put your scripts here

    //--><!]]>
</script>
```

ADDITIONAL NOTES

- These two code blocks do not change anything in modern HTML5 browsers.
- These two code blocks will allow your CSS and JavaScript to work normally as before in HTML5 browsers but hide CSS and JavaScript from very old browsers (pre-2001) that do not support those technologies.
- XHTML browsers will now parse your CSS and JavaScript as before but not allow special characters like `<`, `>`, and `&` to be interpreted as markup or entities/escaped characters which would generate parsing errors. They are CDATA now.
- XML parsers of your page will not understand your CSS and JavaScript, of course, but will accept any type of text you add in there and not try and parse them as markup. They are CDATA now.

HOW THE EXAMPLES WORK

For modern HTML5-supporting browsers, because `script` and `style` elements act like CDATA, all markup is ignored and treated as characters. So comment markers `<!--` and `-->` inside `script` and `style` tags are ignored. Older browsers (pre-2001) that do not know scripts or CSS do not treat `script` and `style` elements as CDATA-supporting elements. They will recognize the HTML comment tags so will comment out all the CSS and JavaScript between them. Note that some browsers do know CSS and scripts but also read the HTML comments, so we close out the first comment (`<!--/*-->`), then they are forced to read the `<![CDATA[/*>` block (used for XHTML and XML parsers) which to them becomes an empty unknown element to these browsers and so is ignored. The HTML comment that follows last in the block is designed to hide all the CSS and scripts from there to the end of the block. The final `<!]]>` is another ignored empty element that closes the unknown CDATA markup tag for those that still read it.

For XHTML, these parsers read all the code inside these tags as HTML. They also need a CDATA element wrapped around all CSS and JavaScript in the block so they act like HTML5 browsers. They do not read the content inside these elements as CDATA yet. XHTML parsers will read the HTML comment tags, but knowing CSS and JavaScript comments as well, they will be ended early. The `<![CDATA[` element is then read and starts the CDATA block for them, as it is a known HTML element in the XHTML W3C recommendations. It then wraps around all styles and scripts inside the tags till `]]>` ends it, creating a true CDATA wrapper that now hides XML characters correctly for them. Everything inside the CDATA block is interpreted like HTML5 parsers do now - as normal CSS and scripts - but to the XHTML parser no longer recognize HTML markup inside them. Because old and new XHTML browsers all know CSS and JavaScript, they still parse and process that code correctly now, ignoring XML reserved characters now.

XML parsers know HTML comments but not CSS and JavaScript comments, so those parsers would hide everything between the comment tags. Since they do not need to know or parse CSS and JavaScript code, it is not needed.

Your HTML5 page is fully cross-compatible with modern HTML5 and XHTML5 browsers, older HTML/XHTML browsers, very old 1990's non-supporting CSS/script browsers, and various XML parsers, old and new! Enjoy

Comment: So glad that I found this thread after 2/28/2021 so this answer was already there - thanks for all the details!

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps see: http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/HTML_vs._XHTML

> <![CDATA[...]]> is a a bogus comment.

In HTML, `<script>` is already protected -- this is why sometimes it must be written as `a =  "<" + "/script>"`, to avoid confusing the browser. Note that the code is valid *outside* a CDATA in HTML.

Comment: I think the best way to escape the end tag is "<\/script>". I've read that some parsers check only for "</", not "</script>"

Comment: @marcus You are correct and that `</` is the only special token in this context. My *newer* answers on the subject concur as I've had my knowledge updated over time ;-) I will update this. That being said, it seems common to have the `</scr` + `ipt>` split,  and I don't know of a mainstream *browser* where it doesn't work...