# Is it a good practice to ignore script type?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML5 <script> declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622091/html5-script-declarations)

I've heard a few people say that you don't need to specify a `type="text/javascript"` in a `<script>` tag, as this is the default type.

Is there any downside if I open my script tags as `<script>` instead of the more verbose `<script type="text/javascript">`?

Comment: @kojiro my question is not specific to html5.

Comment: Not really a dup.  This is a more general question.

Comment: @Christophe I inferred that the few people you heard saying that were talking about the fact that HTML5 had defined a default type. The default type is *not* specified in HTML4.

Comment: @kojiro yes, that's a good point, but the comments I heard (or read) were for older browsers and doctypes as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML4 the `type` attribute is required:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1

In HTML5 it is not.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/script.html

If you are going to use HTML4, then *good practice* certainly includes adhering to its specifications. If you're using HTML5, then it's pretty clear that `<script>` without a `type` is `text/javascript`, so you can safely omit it.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. But in practice do you have examples in html4 where omitting the type would cause issues?

Comment: @Christophe No, because browsers are designed to deal with bad HTML. That doesn't mean it's a good idea to write what you can get away with. Your question specifically is a bit of a trap, because we can already assume (because of HTML5) that future implementations of browsers will assume a default type, but in general, writing invalid HTML that works right now is wrong precisely because it may not work in future browsers.

Comment: I agree that it's a bit of a trap, that's precisely why I am seeking advice from the community! (before trying to save a couple bytes)

Comment: @Christophe but there's an easy out: Use HTML5, and don't include a `type`.

Comment: @kojiro Except that doesn't work if you have to support older browsers.

Comment: @Beska What browsers? How old?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You absolutely can omit the type. Make sure your document type is HTML5 **[if you care for validity.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1)**

```
<!doctype html>
```

It will work just as fine though with any browser you can think of.

It won't be considered "good practice" to break the specifications if you're not using HTML5 though :)

Comment: does this work with non-html5 browsers still existing in the market?

Comment: @Truth So how about non-html5 documents?

Comment: @Christophe:  It **works** fine, it won't be as valid though, if you care as much.

Comment: I believe the question said 'is it a good practice'? Thus, I absolutely don't agree with your 'yes'. It's definitely a *bad* practice (in HTML<5), even if you can't name a browser which doesn't handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the script type attribute is not required when using HTML5, it should be used no matter what, all the time. It is good practice to use it every time when including a script into an HTML document. It doesn't hurt to add it, but it may hurt to not add it. Older browsers may not recognize the script if the type attribute is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing a desktop website for an intranet (internetcafé perhaps), you can write:

```
<script>
   $(functions(){});
</script>
```

If you use HTML or XHTML for the internet, I suggest you write your script tags like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
   // functions
   $(functions(){}); 
// ]]>
```

And to complete this for Inline CSS since we're at it:

```
<style type="text/css">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    /* tags */
    html, body {}
/* ]]> */
</style>
```

This way, whatever kind of character you put in there should be a valid character

**EDIT**
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Uses_of_CDATA_sections